# TeamCity iOS build fails with "Cannot start build runner"

Tags: ios, xcode, teamcity

I'm currently using TeamCity 8.1.5 for continuous integration of an iOS app. I updated the build agent from OS X Yosemite to OS X El Capitan and Xcode 7.2.1 (7C1002). After the update the build fails with the following error message:

```
[Step 4/4] Failed to run build: Invalid plist file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiOSPlatformSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/Device.xcspec
[Step 4/4] java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid plist file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiOSPlatformSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/Device.xcspec
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:128)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.SpecListHelper.doReadSpecs(SpecListHelper.java:36)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.SpecListHelper.readSpecs(SpecListHelper.java:20)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.ApplePlatform.readSpecs(ApplePlatform.java:142)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.ApplePlatform.<init>(ApplePlatform.java:76)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.AppleSdkManager.readPlatforms(AppleSdkManager.java:123)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.AppleSdkManager.initComponent(AppleSdkManager.java:83)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.xcode.AppCodeUtil.applyAdditionalInit(AppCodeUtil.java:63)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.xcode.AppCodeCommonUtil.runWithAppCodeEnvironment(AppCodeCommonUtil.java:116)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.appCode.AppCodeBuildProcess.call(AppCodeBuildProcess.java:68)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.appCode.AppCodeBuildProcess.call(AppCodeBuildProcess.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.jetbrains.cidr.xcode.InvalidSpecException: Object 'Name' not found in {
 Identifier = com.apple.build-system.native
 Type = BuildSystem
 BasedOn = embedded:com.apple.build-system.native
 Properties = [{
 Values = [1, 2, 1,2]
 DisplayName = Targeted Device Family
 DisplayValues = [iPhone, iPad, iPhone/iPad]
 Type = Enumeration
 Category = Deployment
 Name = TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY
 Description = The build system uses the selected device to set the correct value for the UIDeviceFamily key it adds to the target's Info.plist file.
 Basic = YES
}, {
 DisplayName = Enable Bitcode
 Description = Activating this setting indicates that the target or project should generate bitcode during compilation for platforms and architectures which support it.  For Archive builds, bitcode will be generated in the linked binary for submission to the app store.  For other builds, the compiler and linker will check whether the code complies with the requirements for bitcode generation, but will not generate actual bitcode. [ENABLE_BITCODE]
 Name = ENABLE_BITCODE
 Type = Boolean
 Category = BuildOptions
 DefaultValue = NO
}]
}
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.xcode.Dictionary.notNull(Dictionary.java:253)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.xcode.Dictionary.getNotNullString(Dictionary.java:162)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.buildSystem.AppleBuildSystem.<init>(AppleBuildSystem.java:50)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.ApplePlatform$5.create(ApplePlatform.java:145)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.ApplePlatform$5.create(ApplePlatform.java:142)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.SpecListHelper.addObject(SpecListHelper.java:49)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.frameworks.SpecListHelper.doReadSpecs(SpecListHelper.java:32)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to update the TeamCity server to the [latest version](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/) (9.1.6 at the time of writing). The build agent on the Mac auto-updated aswell, and the build works again.